# Xamarin Android GridLayout - rowspan works in designer but not in emulator

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2017, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

I am trying to design a form where I have 6 buttons. 1 button will take up half the screen and the other buttons will each take up the rest of the screen space. I decided to use a GridLayout where I have 10 rows, the first button has a row span of 5 and each of the other buttons have a row span of one. Essentially I expected the button with a row span of 5 to be 5 times larger than the other buttons. This looks correct in the designer but not on the emulator. Does anyone have any ideas how to create a layout like this?

Designer: (what I am expecting to see)
[Link to Designer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFi4v.png)

Emulator: (what I actually see)
[Link to Emulator screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CwclU.png)

Main.axml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:p1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    p1:layout_width="match_parent"
    p1:layout_height="match_parent"
    p1:id="@+id/gridLayout1"
    p1:rowCount="10"
    p1:orientation="vertical">
    <Button
        p1:text="Button"
        p1:layout_gravity="fill"
        p1:layout_rowSpan="5"
        p1:id="@+id/button1" />
    <Button
        p1:text="Button"
        p1:layout_rowSpan="1"
        p1:layout_gravity="fill"
        p1:id="@+id/button2" />
    <Button
        p1:text="Button"
        p1:layout_rowSpan="1"
        p1:layout_gravity="fill"
        p1:id="@+id/button3" />
    <Button
        p1:text="Button"
        p1:layout_rowSpan="1"
        p1:layout_gravity="fill"
        p1:id="@+id/button4" />
    <Button
        p1:text="Button"
        p1:layout_rowSpan="1"
        p1:layout_gravity="fill"
        p1:id="@+id/button5" />
    <Button
        p1:text="Button"
        p1:layout_rowSpan="1"
        p1:layout_gravity="fill"
        p1:id="@+id/button6" />
</GridLayout>
```

I had a look and couldn't find any help for this online after a few hours of searching. All of the tutorials I tried did not work according to what I needed.

I am using Visual Studio 2017

I have the following SDK installed (I installed a few days ago using the visual studio installer and selecting xamarin under packages, so this is pretty much a default install.)

SDK:
[Installed SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OGL5.png)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to add `p1:layout_rowWeight="5"` in your first button.

Comment: @Billy Thanks for the reply but that did not work. I have decided to change my design for now, but I will leave the question up in case someone has an answer in future.

Comment: Have you tried in other Emulator?

Comment: @Billy I have not, I'll give it a try. Thx